# create or copy the dashboard from obiee webservices java api

Tags: java, business-intelligence, obiee

I am using obiee 11g version. I am trying to copy objects from one version to another using the `readobjects` and `writeobjects` methods available in WebCatalogService. I can able to copy reports from one server to another but when it comes to dashboard information, I couldn't able to copy. Please let me know whether it is possible with obiee 11g writeObjects() or not.

Code:

```
locator.setSAWSessionServiceSoapEndpointAddress(wsdl+"?SoapImpl=nQSessionService");
            locator.getSAWSessionServiceSoapAddress();
            soap = locator.getSAWSessionServiceSoap();
            sessionID = soap.logon(adminUsername, adminPassword);
 WebCatalogServiceLocator webcatlocator = new WebCatalogServiceLocator();
         webcatlocator.setWebCatalogServiceSoapEndpointAddress(wsdl+"?SoapImpl=webCatalogService");
         webcatlocator.getWebCatalogServiceSoapAddress();
         WebCatalogServiceSoap webcatsoap = webcatlocator.getWebCatalogServiceSoap();
                            CatalogObject[] report = webcatsoap.readObjects(path1, true, errorMode, returnOptions,sessionID);


ErrorInfo[] ff = webcatsoap.writeObjects(report, true, true,errorMode, sessionID1);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Dashboard objects are not creating as dashboards , it is creating as folder